# Remove Left Padding Char from String

Tags: vb.net

I have the data with the pattern of 8 char in my string. Those data are form from digits. Example: 00000001, 00004235, 081035670. Is that any methods in vb i can use to remove all the left padding zero from each of the strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [String.TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it removes the leading character (you could also use an array and remove a set of characters).

```
Dim lines as List(Of String) = From {"00000001", "00004235", "081035670"}
For Each str as String in lines
    Console.WriteLine(str.TrimStart("0"c)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Just convert it to Integer and convert back to string

```
Dim data As String = "00000001"
data = Convert.ToInt32(data).ToString()
MessageBox.Show(data)
```

**UPDATED:**

`String.TrimStart()` is better solution (answered by jmoreno)